# On locally injectivity of continous $g(x,y,t)=f(x,y+t)$ with $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ continous

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question:

> Does there exist a function  $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ which is locally injective, but $g(x,y,t)=f(x,y+t)$ is not.

The reason I am asking this question is because in the book: Differential geometry of curves and surfaces by M. Do Carmo in one of his proofs(page 71) he shows that if f is differentiable and is $det(df)\neq0$ then $g(x,y,t)=f(x,y+t)$ is for sure locally injective.

But, what in the case where $f$ is continous but not differentiable? Or where it is differentialbe, injective, but $det(df)(p)=0$ for some $p$

Comment: The title is not consistent with the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry sorry, I adapted the question heavily and forgot to change the title. I think now it's okay. Please, feel free to edit anything you don't like